# MongoDB "_id" is null when saving via Camel-MongoDB component

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

We are using MongoDB 2.6.12 and have recently upgraded Camel to 2.18.1 and the "mongo-java-driver" to 3.4.1.

We are using the Camel component "camel-mongodb" and have a route:

```
    <camel:route id="save">
        <from uri="direct:save"/>
        <camel:process ref="myProcessor"/>
        <camel:to uri="mongodb:mongoDBConnectionBean?database=abc&amp;collection=xyz&amp;operation=save"/>
    </camel:route>
```

The "MyProcessor" basically looks like this:

```
   public void process(Exchange exchange) {
       Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
       if (body instanceof DBObject) {
           DBObject newObject = (DBObject) body;

          //some more logic here manipulating "newObject"
          //but "newObject" does not have a field "_id"

           exchange.getIn().setBody(newObject);
       } else {
           exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
       }
    }
```

The result is that the object gets stored in MongoDB but for some reason the "_id" field is set to "null". This did not happen before.

---

### UPDATE:

I took a closer look at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbProducer.createDoSave where this code does the "upsert":

```
MongoCollection e = this.calculateCollection(exchange1);
BasicDBObject saveObj = (BasicDBObject)exchange1.getIn().getMandatoryBody(BasicDBObject.class);
UpdateOptions options = (new UpdateOptions()).upsert(true);
BasicDBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject("_id", saveObj.get("_id"));
UpdateResult result = e.replaceOne(queryObject, saveObj, options);
```

Now in my opinion the problem is that MongoDB on a "replaceOne" takes the "_id" of the "queryObject" (which is null in my case") and inserts "saveObj" with this "_id". (See: [MongoDB Java Client stores "_id" as null on "replaceOne"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326863/mongodb-java-client-stores-id-as-null-on-replaceone))

This behaviour can also be seen in the mongo shell:

```
> db.abc.replaceOne({"_id":null}, {"test":"1"}, {"upsert": true})
> db.abc.find()
{ "_id" : null, "test" : "1" }
```

Therefore on the one hand I think this is a problem in the mongo-camel component code on the other hand I think I must be missing something because else a lot of people would be having this problem.

Comment: I have debugged the camel-mongo code and could reproduce using the java mongo driver directly (doing the same as the camel-mongo code does). I have created another question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326863/mongodb-java-client-stores-id-as-null-on-replaceone

Comment: Just use the `insert` operation if all you're doing is inserting. If you want to do a save, make sure you retrieve the whole object first before updating.

Comment: I have the same problem. It is very bad "improvement" in camel mongo component. I use 'save' operation because some times it is update and sometimes it is insert/ And now, I should check objects before save and use two endpoints with different operations/