# MongoDB Java Client stores "_id" as null on "replaceOne"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

We have upgraded (from 2.11.1) to

```
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
```

Now when we do this:

```
        UpdateOptions options = (new UpdateOptions()).upsert(true);
        BasicDBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject("_id", newObject.get("_id"));
        //where newObject.get("_id") returns "null", i.e. same as
        //BasicDBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject("_id", null);
        UpdateResult result = collection.replaceOne(queryObject, newObject, options);
```

will insert a new document with "_id" set to null (even though no object with _id of null existed previously in the collection). When we do

```
        collection.insertOne(newObject);
```

instead then a proper "_id" is generated. Why does "replaceOne" does not generate a proper _id?

Comment: Can you show what is available on newObject before executing replaceOne?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior for `replaceOne`.

> MongoDB will add the _id field to the replacement document if it is
>   not specified in either the filter or replacement documents. If _id is
>   present in both, the values must be equal.

So it uses the `_id` as null when creating a new document.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be right even though I certainly would not expect that behaviour. Why would I want the "_id" from the filter-object (especially if it is null) be used as the "_id" of the newly created object?

Comment: Mongodb allows one null Id value document. You can do a null check; if the _id value is null then use insertOne else repalceOne.